# Getting ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 when running a React.js app

Tags: mysql, node.js, web3js

Im creating a web3 app that uses React.js and when I try to run the program with yarn/npm I get this error message:

```
ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at /Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:123:19
    at tryCatcher (/Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/jendala/Documents/Current NFT/Website/React/copy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:462:21) {
  parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    fatal: true
  },
  original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    fatal: true
  }
}
```

Here is the SQL connection file:

````
const AbstractConnectionManager = require('../abstract/connection-manager');
const SequelizeErrors = require('../../errors');
const Promise = require('../../promise');
const { logger } = require('../../utils/logger');
const DataTypes = require('../../data-types').mysql;
const momentTz = require('moment-timezone');
const debug = logger.debugContext('connection:mysql');
const parserStore = require('../parserStore')('mysql');

/**
 * MySQL Connection Manager
 *
 * Get connections, validate and disconnect them.
 * AbstractConnectionManager pooling use it to handle MySQL specific connections
 * Use https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2 to connect with MySQL server
 *
 * @extends AbstractConnectionManager
 * @returns Class<ConnectionManager>
 * @private
 */

class ConnectionManager extends AbstractConnectionManager {
  constructor(dialect, sequelize) {
    sequelize.config.port = sequelize.config.port || 3306;
    super(dialect, sequelize);
    this.lib = this._loadDialectModule('mysql2');
    this.refreshTypeParser(DataTypes);
  }

  _refreshTypeParser(dataType) {
    parserStore.refresh(dataType);
  }

  _clearTypeParser() {
    parserStore.clear();
  }

  static _typecast(field, next) {
    if (parserStore.get(field.type)) {
      return parserStore.get(field.type)(field, this.sequelize.options, next);
    }
    return next();
  }

  /**
   * Connect with MySQL database based on config, Handle any errors in connection
   * Set the pool handlers on connection.error
   * Also set proper timezone once connection is connected.
   *
   * @param {Object} config
   * @returns {Promise<Connection>}
   * @private
   */
  connect(config) {
    const connectionConfig = Object.assign({
      host: config.host,
      port: config.port,
      user: config.username,
      flags: '-FOUND_ROWS',
      password: config.password,
      database: config.database,
      timezone: this.sequelize.options.timezone,
      typeCast: ConnectionManager._typecast.bind(this),
      bigNumberStrings: false,
      supportBigNumbers: true
    }, config.dialectOptions);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const connection = this.lib.createConnection(connectionConfig);

      const errorHandler = e => {
        // clean up connect & error event if there is error
        connection.removeListener('connect', connectHandler);
        connection.removeListener('error', connectHandler);
        reject(e);
      };

      const connectHandler = () => {
        // clean up error event if connected
        connection.removeListener('error', errorHandler);
        resolve(connection);
      };

      // don't use connection.once for error event handling here
      // mysql2 emit error two times in case handshake was failed
      // first error is protocol_lost and second is timeout
      // if we will use `once.error` node process will crash on 2nd error emit
      connection.on('error', errorHandler);
      connection.once('connect', connectHandler);
    })
      .tap(() => { debug('connection acquired'); })
      .then(connection => {
        connection.on('error', error => {
          switch (error.code) {
            case 'ESOCKET':
            case 'ECONNRESET':
            case 'EPIPE':
            case 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST':
              this.pool.destroy(connection);
          }
        });

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if (!this.sequelize.config.keepDefaultTimezone) {
            // set timezone for this connection
            // but named timezone are not directly supported in mysql, so get its offset first
            let tzOffset = this.sequelize.options.timezone;
            tzOffset = /\//.test(tzOffset) ? momentTz.tz(tzOffset).format('Z') : tzOffset;
            return connection.query(`SET time_zone = '${tzOffset}'`, err => {
              if (err) { reject(err); } else { resolve(connection); }
            });
          }

          // return connection without executing SET time_zone query
          resolve(connection);
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        switch (err.code) {
          case 'ECONNREFUSED':
            throw new SequelizeErrors.ConnectionRefusedError(err);
          case 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR':
            throw new SequelizeErrors.AccessDeniedError(err);
          case 'ENOTFOUND':
            throw new SequelizeErrors.HostNotFoundError(err);
          case 'EHOSTUNREACH':
            throw new SequelizeErrors.HostNotReachableError(err);
          case 'EINVAL':
            throw new SequelizeErrors.InvalidConnectionError(err);
          default:
            throw new SequelizeErrors.ConnectionError(err);
        }
      });
  }

  disconnect(connection) {
    // Don't disconnect connections with CLOSED state
    if (connection._closing) {
      debug('connection tried to disconnect but was already at CLOSED state');
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    return Promise.fromCallback(callback => connection.end(callback));
  }

  validate(connection) {
    return connection
      && !connection._fatalError
      && !connection._protocolError
      && !connection._closing
      && !connection.stream.destroyed;
  }
}

module.exports = ConnectionManager;
module.exports.ConnectionManager = ConnectionManager;
module.exports.default = ConnectionManager;```



I've been reading that it could be something to do with the SQL connection but am unsure if that is truly the case here.

Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: Your localhost is refusing the mysql connection. It can mean few things. 1) The mysql service is not running. 2) It's not accepting connections from the IP address of your app (posibly localhost as well, possibly external server).

Comment: @PetrHejda It can only mean one of those things: it isn't running. Anything else would cause a different error.